# Purely inseparable isogeny

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

How to prove purely inseparable isogeny between two abelian varieties is radical (universally injective)?  Purely inseparable morphism means the extension between the two function fields is purely inseparable.

Answer (score 6):

See Proposition 5.6 of the book on abelian varieties by [Edixhoven-van der Geer-Moonen](http://gerard.vdgeer.net/AV.pdf).